# Create Two or More Mongos Connection Objects in Node JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

We can configure two more mongos server ip in to nodejs application.If we are configured 3 Mongos Ip means Which ip will be used whether it is based on Round Robin or any concern, how its works.

Its Mainly help full for what **automatic fail over** or **load balancing**.

How we find which mongos ip used for current operation

Comment: Driver will create pool of available mangos and pick whichever is available.

Comment: How it will pick. How we can see which one is picked. Let consider all Mongos are working so that time which one will be select. Its Round Robin   or same IP will be elected. I need to Know Detail Please any one help to me

Comment: No, you can't pick mongos of your choice. See documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-query-router/

Comment: We can't pick MongoS. How the Node JS driver picks available mongos and where we can see which Monogs in Currently use. How to achieve load balance in mongos using  Node Js

Answer (score 0):

**Replication** is the process of synchronizing data across multiple servers. Replication provides redundancy and increases data availability with multiple copies of data on different database servers, replication protects a database from the loss of a single server. Replication also allows you to recover from hardware failure and service interruptions.

MongoDB achieves replication by the use of replica set. A replica set is a group of mongod instances that host the same data set. In a replica one node is `primary node` that receives all write operations. All other instances, `secondaries`, apply operations from the primary so that they have the same data set. Replica set can have only one primary node.

Replica set is a group of two or more nodes (generally minimum 3 nodes are required).
In a replica set one node is `primary node` and remaining nodes are `secondary`.
All data replicates from primary to secondary node.
At the time of automatic failover or maintenance, election establishes for primary and a new primary node is elected.
After the recovery of failed node, it again join the replica set and works as a secondary node.

start the mongodb server by specifying --replSet option.
 Basic syntax of --replSet is given below:

```
mongod --port "PORT" --dbpath "YOUR_DB_DATA_PATH" --replSet "REPLICA_SET_INSTANCE_NA
```

like this

```
mongod --port 27017 --dbpath "D:\set up\mongodb\data" --replSet rs0
```

To add members to replica set, start mongod instances on multiple machines. Now start a mongo client and issue a command `rs.add(HOST_NAME:PORT)`

You can add mongod instance to replica set only when you are connected to primary node. To check whether you are connected to primary or not issue the command db.isMaster() in mongo client.